# Not able to use CSS3 in visual studio 2010

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, css

I am using Visual studio 2010 service pack 1 to design websites but i am not able to use 'CSS3' in it. I have tried to use some border properties for front page but it shows error 'Not supported'.

Comment: i think you are not able to use intellisense for css3. because css3 properties depend on browser not ide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install **[CSS 3 Intellisense Schema](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/7211bcac-091b-4a32-be2d-e797be0db210)** :

it adds CSS3 intellisense schema to visual studio 2010 which improves developer web designing and support css 3 properties.

In **SP1** there are a few improvements in the CSS3 support as well, though not as elaborate as with HTML5. The editor now supports the more advanced selectors such as div:nth-child(2n+1) without giving validation errors and the new color values rgba, hsl, hsla and 8 digit hex values are also supported.

[Reference](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2011/01/27/html5-amp-css3-in-visual-studio-2010-sp1.aspx)

Comment: Thank you.This is what i needed.